# Mac specific optimizations in ~/.gitconfig

Tags: git, macos, configuration, dvcs

I read that discussion about the content of "~/.gitconfig" on Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267761/what-does-your-gitconfig-contain

I know some Mac specific optimizations, such as using "mate" as default editor:

```
[core]
    editor = mate -w
```

or using opendiff as diff editor:

```
[diff]
    external = opendiff
```

Do you know other Mac specific optimizations (and/or tools) that I could install/configure in "~/.gitconfig" file in order to get a very user-friendly git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to keep the default `diff` command internal, for quick summaries at the terminal, and access the more advanced diff programs (I use MacVim) using the `difftool` commmand. I describe the set up procedure [here](http://jeetworks.org/setting-up-git-to-use-your-diff-viewer-or-editor-of-choice/). The Mac-specific part is in my wrapper script, where I facultatively launch MacVim if it is available, then default to regular Vim. You can adapt to use TextMate, of course, if that is your preference.

Answer (score 23):

I use opendiff and textmate as external tools for git. You can configure them by running the following commands in bash:

```
#TextMate as the default editor
git config --global core.editor "mate -w"

#Opendiff (FileMerge) to resolve merge conflicts:
git config --global merge.tool opendiff

#Opendiff (FileMerge) as diff tool
git config --global diff.tool opendiff
```

Alternatively you can configure the gitconfig file by adding the following:

```
[diff]
    tool = opendiff

[merge]
    tool = opendiff

[core]
    editor = mate -w
```

The difftool and mergetool is only available after version 1.6.3

Answer (score 4):

Since git reuses the same temporary file for commit messages, I recommend using

```
[core]
    editor = mate -wl1
```

so TextMate puts the cursor onto the first line every time instead of remembering the cursor position from last time.

And if you create the following shell script...

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/bin/git-opendiff.sh
#
/usr/bin/opendiff "$2" "$5" -merge "$1"
```

...and configure git to use it as external diff tool...

```
$ git config --global diff.external ~/bin/git-opendiff.sh
```

...you can use opendiff for diffs and merges.